# Linear probability model

Tags: regression, logit, probit, linear

Is there any advantage or any situation when the Linear probability model is superior than Logit model and Probit model, apart from its simplicity.

Comment: Superior in what sense? If you think in terms of generalization, then according to Free Lunch theorem no model is the best or superior to all others considering all possible datasets.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually i want to know that in what circumstances linear probability  model can be preferred over Logit and probit model?

Comment: This is about link functions. The probit link function enables to deal with probability units, while the logit link function with log odds. It is computationally simpler to work with the latter. The logit link function is also useful when working with multinomial dependent variables. All in all it seems that the difference is about how the predicted value is used.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a special case where no link function is superior to any other link function. In that case a linear probability model (identify link function) is as good as a logit, probit, cloglog, or any other link function you can imagine, and the simplicitly of interpreting a linear probability model could in that special case decisively tip the balance.

That special case is a fully saturated model, i.e. a model that includes only categorical explanatory/predictor/independent/right-hand-side/$x$-variables *and* includes all possible (higher order) interactions. In that case the predicted probabilities will be exactly the same regardless which link function you use and correspond to the means of the dependent variable within each combination of predictor variables. Since the predicted probabilities are guaranteed to be exactly the same regardless which link function is used, the fit of these different models is also exactly the same.