# Help with understanding logistic regression's $R^2$ value

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, r-squared

I have a set of ordinal varies (0,1,2,3,4) and I'm trying to do binary logistic regression with a dichotomous variable (0,1). These are the values, where the numerator is = 1 and the denominator is = (0+1):

```
0:  476 / 2384  (20.0%)  
1:  428 / 1908  (22.4%)  
2:  368 / 1277  (28.9%)  
3:  101 /  376  (26.9%)  
4:   23 /   64  (35.9%)
```

When I run these with the binary logistic regression tool in SPSS I get $r^2 = .007$. However, when I graph them as percents in Excel, the linear trendline looks a lot better, and has $r^2 =.8647$.

From my understanding, you can't use a linear regression for categorical variables because it can be negative, but it looks like the data is better than $r^2=.007$.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "$R^2$" in logistic regression as there is in linear regression.  Instead there are a variety of *pseudo-*$R^2$*s* (see [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/)).  None of them mean the same thing as the $R^2$ from linear regression, so they shouldn't be compared (it may help you to read through some of the threads listed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r-squared%2blogistic?tab=Votes)).

When you run this in Excel, you are using what's called the *linear probability model*.  It is possible for it to be an acceptable model (see: [Linear probability model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144092/linear-probability-model)).  I might worry a little that you have fewer observations at higher levels of $X$.  I might especially worry about assuming linearity given that $X$ is ordinal.  You are making a strong assumption about the nature of $X$; you need to be clear about that.